# Wordpress PHP giving error on loading site

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to load my wordpress site. After loading it is giving me a 500 error which says `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sI' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ')' in /tmp/SESS_48cd7517d21176f980daa5502d9efb31 on line 262`. I tried to create a test folder, installed manually wordpress and changed adding old wp-content and wp-config folders and files, but that didn't fix my issue.

[My Site](http://ezeehomeservice.com/)

And one more error on loading wp-admin page:

[error on wp-admin page](http://ezeehomeservice.com/wp-admin)

Fatal error: Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /home/company/public_html/example.com/wp-includes/load.php on line 317

Comment: Did you install a theme or child theme recently or modify any code? If so, try and remove the theme/child theme or try and remove your code modifications and see if that helps.

Comment: Ooh.. This also kinda seems like it might be a hack / malware too. There's really no reason why WordPress should be loading anything from a /tmp/ folder unless maybe you have some weird caching plugin running or something.

Comment: No i did not ones server was down from then  its is showing the same error